# Cannot change the indentation of project files in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation

I wast to change the indent of all the files in all the projects to 2 spaces. I have no `.editoconfig` in my project. Even if there is, I have disabled its overriding. I have made the same changes in `Project` and `Default` level formatters.

I have size as 2 spaces for `Tab size`, `Indent` and `Continuation Indent`.

But whenever I press enter in a new file, I get a 4 space tab and 4 space indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `.editorconfig`, just make sure you have the [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7294) installed. If not, first check `Editor -> Code Style` for the default options, then check `Editor -> Code Style -> Java (for instance)` for the specific options for that file type. Any options specified for a file type will override the defaults.